# How to use websockets.broadcast() in while True loop

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, async-await, python-asyncio

In this function, I want to get video frames and predict them, then broadcast predicted result to all subscribers, but when I run this function, clients can't receive result. Because code don't return any error, I don't know what happened. How could I modify this function?

```
import websockets
import cv2 
import asyncio

async def echo(websocket, path):
    vidCap = cv2.VideoCapture('test.mp4')
    while True:
        ret, image = vidCap.read()
        if ret:
            out_json=predict(image)
            websockets.broadcast(clients,out_json)
```

I attempted to utilize threads in this function, but the result doesn't change. While the server program is running, the client doesn't receive any results. However, after stopping the server program, I noticed that the client received the results. Why is this happening?

---

Edit:Sorry for my bad describe.Let me revised this question. Now I can send result to 1st client,but when I want to run 2nd or 3rd clients,there are no data can be received because server is stuck in the while loop. How should I revise my code?

Here is Server.py. Predict function is a DNN model.

```
import websockets
import cv2 
import asyncio
import time 

def predict(image):
    return "test"

async def echo(websocket, path):
    global vidCap,i
    while True:
        ret, image = vidCap.read()
        if ret:
            start = time.time()
            result=predict(image)
            websockets.broadcast(clients,result)
            end = time.time()
            print("exec time：%f s" % (end - start))

async def handler(websocket, path):
    clients.add(websocket)
    try:
        await echo(websocket, path)
    finally:
        clients.remove(websocket)

async def serve():                                                                                           
    start_server = await websockets.serve(handler, "localhost", 8765)
    await start_server.wait_closed()
#-------------------------------------#
if __name__ == '__main__':
    vidCap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://xxx.xxx.xx') #rtsp or video
    clients = set()
    asyncio.run(serve())
```

Client.py

```
import websockets
import cv2 
import asyncio
import time 
async def get_result(uri):
    global encode
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        while(True):
            try:
                start = time.time()
                recv_text=await websocket.recv()
                print(recv_text)
                end = time.time()
                print("exec：%f s" % (end - start))
            except:
                pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(get_result("ws://127.0.0.1:8765/ws"))
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: maybe `ret` is always `False` and it doesn't send anything.

Comment: maybe problem is in client code. We can't run client to test this code.

Comment: this function does not use anything async to start with. There are 3 potentially blocking calls inside your while loop, and we know nothing about any of them. I don't think you can get any help with the question as is. Try to write a complete, minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution. Replace:

```
websockets.broadcast(clients,result)
```

with:

```
await asyncio.wait([ws.send(result) for ws in clients])
```

But I don't know what is the difference between them.

Comment: The first one is blocking and never yields back to the eventloop -> no other code has a chance to run. The second one is async so every time it hits the await keyword it releases control back to the eventloop, giving other tasks a chance to run.